# Problems about yyin and yyout using in lex for lexical analysis

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

This is main function for lexical analysis.

If I use `yyin` for getting data from file, `yyout` execute and writes to file, but when I give codes from terminal `yyout` isn't working. How can I solve that?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

extern FILE *yyin, *yyout; 
    char *input;
    printf("flexing there\n argc=%d\n argv[0]=%s argv[1]=%s \n",argc,argv[0],argv[1]);
    if(argc > 1 && strstr(argv[1],".g++") != NULL){
    printf("we will read your file = %s\n",argv[1]);
    
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 
  
  
    }
    else if(argc > 1){
        printf("your file type is wrong ,must be .g++ type\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("enter your code please\n ");
    }
    yyout = fopen("outputlex.txt", "w"); 
    yylex();
    
    
    
   return 0;

}
```

I use yyout at rule section like that

```
%%

"("         fprintf(yyout,"OP_OP\n");

%%
```

Comment: Please provide some evidence for "yyout doesn't work".  Where do you even use `yyout`? How do you test? What result did you get, and what did you expect? See [ask] and especially how to  create a [mre]

Comment: What does "give codes from terminal" mean?

Comment: Added new infos,thanks for evaluations

Comment: May be you just forgot to send a CTRL+D when you finished? Btw your code works here: I type a single `(` char to STDIN after start, then type CTRL+D, and the file `output.txt` contains the string `OP_OP`.

Comment: @airween  ,thanks it is working with that combination, but why it doesnt working with enter , with enter doesnt write to file, just writes on terminal,

Comment: @Srknsmsk: ENTER is a symbol ("\n", or "\r\n"), your parser eats that. if you wants to terminate the parser working, you can make a special rule. If there isn't any explicit call, EOF will call the `yyterminate()`, which stops the whole flow (as I know...). Just check your compiled C source by flex.

Comment: @airween: Or you could just [read the flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html#index-yyterminate_0028_0029)

Comment: @rici: could you clarify your tip?

Comment: @airween: the last paragraph in the linked page.

Comment: @rici: you mean this? "By default, `yyterminate()` is also called when an end-of-file is encountered." I also wrote this above: "If there isn't any explicit call, EOF will call the `yyterminate()`".

Comment: @airween: yes. That paragraph explains what yyterminate actually does, when it is called automatically, and how to modify its behaviour. I think getting all that in one paragraph is easier than trawling through the generated code. But that's just me.

Comment: Vote plus for question pls guys

Answer (score 0):

In C, when you write to a file, the output is kept in a buffer until there is enough data to make it worthwhile writing, typically around 4kb. So if you just write a few bytes, you won't see anything in the file until it is closed.

By contrast, when you write to the terminal, the output is usually only buffered until a newline character is written. And if you write to `stderr`, the output is always immediate.

You can change the buffering for a stream by calling [`setvbuf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html) right after the `fopen`. You can also force  the stream's buffer to be sent using [`fflush`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html).